# Flink S3 Hadoop 2.8.0

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

We were trying to use S3 for Flink backend state and checkpoints and used a bucket in Frankfurt (V4 authentication) It gave the error I posted here ([Cannot access S3 bucket with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004130/cannot-access-s3-bucket-with-hadoop)) and it was due to hadoop. However hadoop 2.8.0 works but there is no Flink support yet.

Guess my question is when will Flink offer a version based on hadoop 2.8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink will probably offer a Hadoop 2.8.0 version once that Hadoop version is released.

In the meantime, you can build Flink yourself with a custom Hadoop version:

`mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=2.8.0`

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to the official release.

Comment: we're shipping now, though it's still stabilising.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop 2.7.x does work with Frankfurt and v4 API endpoints. If you are having problems, check your joda-time version as an odd combination of old joda-time JARs and Java versions causes AWS to get the wrong-formatted timestamp, which it then rejects in the ubiquitous "bad auth" message.

Comment: I used hadoop 2.7.3 and got that error, just copied the AWS, http* and jackson libs from share/hadoop/hdfs/lib to share/hadoop/common/lib as it was complaining about not finding them.

Comment: With hadoop 2.8 I did the same and it worked the first time.